# How to make controller discoverable in core mvc without adding "Controller" suffix?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My understanding is that core mvc (was MVC 6) controllers can be discovered if they end in "Controller" **OR** they derive from the `Controller` class.  At least one place on the web that states this is here http://www.strathweb.com/2015/04/asp-net-mvc-6-discovers-controllers/

But in my tests of a very basic MVC 6 RC1 website the controller is only discovered if it has a "Controller" suffix.  Am I missing something?  So for example the following controller is discovered by the framework:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But this controller is not:

```
public class Home: Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is that the intended behavior?  Can it be changed so that classes that derive from `Controller` are discoverable without the "Controller" suffix?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this, but you can always inherit from `DefaultControllerFactory` and override `GetControllerType` to resolve your controllers any way you want if there isn't. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks,  I've tried to pursue your suggestion but I can't see that `DefaultControllerFactory` has a `GetControlerType` method.  I'm looking at the source code here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Ahh, I missed that this was .net core.  I don't have much experience with that, and some things look like they changed slightly from previous versions.  A quick glance at that code you linked makes me think it would still work, but override `CreateController` instead.  Or possibly mess with the `IControllerActivator` implementation passed in to the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I realize that I was mistaken.  Or rather I misunderstood what I was seeing.

If in fact the controller is named `Home`, as listed in my example, and it inherits from `Controller` it will be considered a `Controller` by the framework and will be found when a route needs a controller called `Home`.

In my case, I was actually wanting to name my Controller `HomeCtlr` rather than `HomeController` and that wasn't working but not because the framework didn't recognize it as a controller.  The real issue was that it was matching a route that needed a controller named `HomeCtlr` rather than one named `Home`.  So in the end I realize I was thinking about this wrong and asked the wrong question.

So the actual answer to the question I asked, is that any class that inherits from the `Controller` class will be considered a controller by the framework.  No "Controller" suffix is needed.  But beware that you can't add some other abbreviated suffix as it will be considered part of the controller name when matching routes to that controller (which of course makes perfect sense!) Duh!